# Copy sheet in Excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

This VBA code prompts the user to input a week number and then shows/hides columns in an Excel worksheet based on that input. Finally, it copies the visible cells to a new worksheet named "Week [week number] Results".

I tried to copy the result of the code to a new sheet in excel, but the created sheet is empty
This is the sheet i want to copy
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HoZ3.png)

```
Sub ShowColumnsAndCopy()

' Get user input for week number or "all"
Dim weekNumber As Variant
weekNumber = InputBox("Enter the week number (1-49) or type 'all' to show all columns:")

' Check if input is valid
If Not (IsNumeric(weekNumber) And weekNumber >= 1 And weekNumber <= 49) And weekNumber <> "all" Then
    MsgBox "Invalid input"
    Exit Sub
End If

' Show first 9 columns
Range("A7:I7").EntireColumn.Hidden = False

' Show all columns if "all" is entered
If weekNumber = "all" Then
    Range("J7").EntireColumn.Resize(1, Columns.Count - 9).Hidden = False
    Exit Sub
End If

' Show columns with week number
Dim col As Integer
col = 10
While col <= 79
    If Cells(7, col).Value = "RAP Week " & weekNumber _
        Or Cells(7, col).Value = "Inventaire Week " & weekNumber _
        Or Cells(7, col).Value = "EDI Week " & weekNumber Then
        Cells(7, col).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Else
        Cells(7, col).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    End If
    col = col + 1
Wend

' Show remainder columns
Range("CA7").Select
Dim lastColumn As Integer
lastColumn = ActiveCell.End(xlToLeft).Column
If lastColumn > 9 Then
    Range("J7:" & Split(Cells(1, lastColumn).Address, "$")(1)).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End If

' Copy result to new sheet
Dim newSheet As Worksheet
Set newSheet = Worksheets.Add(After:=ActiveSheet)
newSheet.Name = "Week " & weekNumber & " Results"
Dim rngCopy As Range
Set rngCopy = Range("A7", Cells(Rows.Count, lastColumn).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
rngCopy.Copy newSheet.Range("A1")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write `Range("A7"...`), you don't tell VBA which sheet you want to use. In that case, VBA will use the `ActiveSheet` - and that changed to the new created sheet (Workbook.Add sets the focus on the new sheet).

You should never rely on the active sheet and instead tell VBA which sheet you want to use. Basically there are two ways to do so: Either assign the sheet to a worksheet variable or use a with clause.

The following piece of code shows the `With`-clause. **You will need to add a "." in front of every occurrence of `Range` and `Cells`** in your code - this will tell VBA that you want to use the object (in this case a Worksheet) defined in the `With`-Clause:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PDB")  

    ' Show first 9 columns
    .Range("A7:I7").EntireColumn.Hidden = False

    ' Show all columns if "all" is entered
    If weekNumber = "all" Then
        .Range("J7").EntireColumn.Resize(1, Columns.Count - 9).Hidden = False
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Show columns with week number
    Dim col As Long
    For col = 10 to 79
        If .Cells(7, col).Value = "RAP Week " & weekNumber _
        Or .Cells(7, col).Value = "Inventaire Week " & weekNumber _
        Or .Cells(7, col).Value = "EDI Week " & weekNumber Then
            .Cells(7, col).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Else
            .Cells(7, col).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next col
    
    (...)
    
End With
```

2 Remarks: (1) Make it a habit to use `Long` instead of `Integer` - `Integer` use only 2 Bytes (while occupying 4 Bytes in memory, so it even doesn't save space) and are often a cause for overflow errors. (2) In your case, a `For`-Loop is better than a `While`-Loop

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked when i added the with clause